# Converting AWS Polly Audio Stream with fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, amazon-polly

I am trying to convert an audio stream from Amazon AWS Polly in Node.js using fluent-ffmpeg.  The documentation says that I can convert a stream, which is what the output of Polly provides, but I am getting an "Invalid input" error.

```
polly.synthesizeSpeech(pollyParams, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err)
} else {
    console.log('Audio')
    console.log(data)
    ffmpeg().input(data.AudioStream).inputOptions(['-ac 2', '-codec:a libmp3lame', '-b:a 48k', '-ar 16000']) 
}
```

Results in:

AudioStream:  }
2017-07-27T14:07:09.335Z    dd75614c-72d4-11e7-b7cd-5d4425c782fc    Error: Invalid input
    at FfmpegCommand.proto.mergeAdd.proto.addInput.proto.input (/var/task/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/options/inputs.js:34:15)

I know the output from Polly is a valid audio stream, because I am able to save it to an S3 bucket.  I would prefer to convert the stream before saving to S3, rather than saving it, picking it up from S3, converting it, and then saving it again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... Looks like a bug with ffmpeg: 
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/616